# What's the problem in this mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064, create-table

I wanted to execute the following statement to create a table for storing various details .Here name of movies will store there "Ratings in integer value" Please help me solve this issue

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    website VARCHAR,
    aboutyou VARCHAR,
    gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    avengers INT NOT NULL,
    inception INT NOT NULL,
    godfather INT NOT NULL,
    mrrobot INT NOT NULL,
    xfiles INT NOT NULL,
    friends INT NOT NULL
);
```

I get error from phpmyadmin as:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'aboutyou VARCHAR,
>       gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>       avengers INT NOT' at line 6

Comment: This is a SQL error not PHP. There is nothing about PHP here. I also would strongly reconsider this schema. TV shows/movies likely should not be in this table. Have a `user` table, have a `entertainment` table (it will store movie and show titles), then have a `user_to_entertainment` (or `user_entertaiment_rating`) table that stores the userid, entertainmentid, and their rating.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely consider your suggestion, Actually I am a beginner this is why my approach is weak . I've started to learn things about php & mysql recently. BTW Your idea is really creative once again thanks ;)

Comment: You can read more about that logic here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Well, I think if you give the query a closer look, you will understand it yourself!**

I guess that the error is due to the fact that you do not provide the VARIABLE for the length of the string. You specify only that you want to use VARCHAR as a data type for the columns website and aboutyou. But the correct form is **VARCHAR(n)**, where n the number of characters you want your string to be. I tried to implement it myself, and when I gave a number enclosed in parentheses, it worked perfectly.

An example, try:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at VARCHAR(5),
    website VARCHAR(55),
    about_you VARCHAR(255),
    gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    avengers INT NOT NULL,
    inception INT NOT NULL,
    godfather INT NOT NULL,
    mrrobot INT NOT NULL,
    xfiles INT NOT NULL,
    friends INT NOT NULL
);
```

I hope that helps and answers your question.
Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Give them length as you did with gender and it will work.

```
 website VARCHAR(50),
 aboutyou VARCHAR(50),

 gender VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Thank You! It helped